# Como pegar o primeiro caractere de uma String e torná-lo maiúsculo armazenando em uma variável?

Tags: c#, .net, string, char

```
        String user,newUser,newPassword, password, resposta, user1,pass1;
        user = "admin";
        password = "123";
        Console.WriteLine("LOGIN\n");

    body:
        Console.WriteLine("Ja possui login?");
        resposta = Console.ReadLine();

        /*
        gostaria de fazer com que a resposta acima lida pelo programa seja convertida para um unico caractere maiusculo para quando fizer a comparação não precisar colocar varias || dentro da condição.
        */

        if (resposta.Equals("N"))
        {
            Console.Write("Digite novo usuario: \n");
            newUser = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Digite nova senha: \n");
            newPassword = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Criado com sucesso!\nAgora faça Login!");

            goto body;

        }
        else if (resposta.Equals("S"))
        {
            Console.Write("Digite usuario: \n");
            user1 = Console.ReadLine();

            if (user1.Equals(user))
            {
                Console.Write("Digite a senha: \n");
                pass1 = Console.ReadLine();

                if (pass1.Equals(password))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Logado com Sucesso!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Senha incorreta, tente novamente:");
                    goto body;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usuario incorreto, tente novamente!");
                goto body;
            }
        }

        Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var c = char.ToUpper(texto[0]);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/UpperChar.cs).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.toupper?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#System_Char_ToUpper_System_Char_).

Mas antes de usar isso, apague todo seu código e comece de novo, desta vez escreva um código sem `goto` e com os recursos do C#. Tem outros erros, mas esses são urgentes. Sugiro aprender por outros meios.

Comment: +1, Aliás, na hora do aprendizado é o melhor momento pra isso, pq depois vai virando vício escrever código "amarrado com arame". Praticamente todos nós acabamos "amarrando com arame" uma hora ou outra em condições menos ideais, mesmo que contra a vontade, mas não pode ser "princípio de vida" se a intenção é programar de verdade.

Comment: Obrigado @Maniero

Comment: Irei reescrever tudo e não vou utilizar o goto. Esta foi uma solução simples apenas para aprendizado, estou aprendendo na universidade e este foi apenas um teste.

Comment: Aprenda fazer do jeito certo, uma vez que faça do jeito errado começa formar uma ideia errada na sua cabeça e vai ficando cada vez mais difícil fazer certo. E veja a melhor forma de dizer obrigado no [tour].

Comment: @Maniero muita diferença de performance comparado ao `StartsWith()`?

Answer (score 0):

Saudações, sugiro que siga as recomendações do @Maniero.

Em resposta a sua pergunta, e apenas para seu conhecimento, segue o exemplo:

**Mude isto:**

```
body:
   Console.WriteLine("Ja possui login?");
   resposta = Console.ReadLine();
```

**Para isto:**

```
body:
   Console.WriteLine("Ja possui login?");
   resposta = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();// basta inserir o ToUpper" Tornar Maiúscula"
```

Comment: Obrigado @Agnaldo eu até pensei nesta solução. Mas não sei por que motivos não estava dando certo. Vou tentqr novamente. Obrigado